# Restore ALL databases with sqlcmd in SQL Server (Express, Docker, 2017)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sqlcmd

These documentation articles

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container?view=sql-server-2017

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database?view=sql-server-2017

Tell us how to restore *individual* databases. I want to restore *all* databases in the file list. Is there a way to do this programmatically from within the `sqlcmd` without involving bash?

Comment: Have you checked - dbatool.io ? Its powershell based and works *mostly* cross platform as well.

Comment: https://dbatools.io/ –No, I haven't. I don't think project teammates would go for installing `pwsh` in this instance. I'm running on Debian and hoping for a SQL-only solution, if one exists. In other words `pwsh` isn't really any better than bash.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you want I would do the following:

1. Create two files - `List.txt` (with the list of DBs you want to
   restore) and `DBRestore.bat` with sqlcmd command to run a stored
   procedure 'DBRestore' inside `SQL Server`
2. Create a stored procedure 'DBRestore' which loads into `SQL Server` temp table the list from the `LIST.txt` and processes it - reads DB name one by one and restores them